# Creating OS version specific RPM file in Hudson

Tags: hudson, rpmbuild

I am a newbie in rpmbuild and Hudson CI tool. I have an RPM build file which is created using Hudson CI tool running on RHEL5 server. Now I want to install that same RPM file on a server with OS version RHEL7. I came to know that there are chances that the installation of the RPM file may fail due OS version incompatibility (as it is created on RHEL5 and will be getting deployed on RHEL7) though I am not sure about it and I cant take the risk of installing the RPM file on that RHEL7 server without proper knowledge. So here are my questions:
1) Are RPM builds specific to RHEL version ?
2) Is there any dynamic configuration changes that can be done in Hudson job to make final rpm build compatible to RHEL7
3) Or do I need to  make any dynamic changes in the SPEC file to  make it RHEL 7 compatible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are *usually* forward compatible. You will need to use something like `mock`, VMs, or Docker containers to build proper RPMs for different OSs.